# How does Linux terminal commands get parse?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell

In the terminal, or shell, on Linux machines you can type certain commands with options, flags, arguments, etc.

```
cd /home/user -p
```

and then when you run the command it get parse and something happen.

I want to make a JavaScript (NodeJS) parser that simply take a string and parse it into tokens so I can use the tokens and execute certain functions how they should execute. Sort of like how Linux shell work.

I was thinking something like this might work.

```
{
    name: "cd",
    flags: ["p"],
    args: ["/home/user"],
}
```

I never done any type of parsing. How would I go about creating my goal? Is there any better way to do it or any libraries that does this for you?

Comment: If you're going to down vote please at least explain why.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, will read that and take it into consideration for future questions. Thanks.